# Make hg log case insensitive?

Tags: mercurial, hg-log

We use `hg log -u MyUser`.

Is there a way to make this case insensitive?  Ie: so hg will return all changesets for MyUser or myuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to make the option case insensitive, but you can specify multiple user on the command line :

```
hg log -u MyUser -u myuser -u Myuser -u myUser
```

I admit this is a little bit tedious, but you can create an [alias](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) if you have to type the command many times. Add this to your hgrc file for example :

```
[alias]
mylog = log -u MyUser -u myuser -u Myuser -u myUser
```

You can now use `hg mylog` insteand of the entire expression.